# .Net: microsoft.identity.client.desktop 4.58.0 failed when assembly.info is included in .net462 (net48) project

Tags: .net, nuget, rider

I tried to update the package of microsoft.identity.client.desktop to the newest version 4.58.0. Target framework is net462
When i update the library i got the error:

Sourcefile "....\obj\Debug\net48\XXXX.XXXX.AssemblyInfo.cs" was not found.

Only for the target framework netstandard2.0 it works. But actually i need net462 for my desktop application. And i also need the assembly.info.

So actually it is not clear, why the compiler returns the error because of the assembly.info. The framework themselve is supported by the library (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Client.Desktop#supportedframeworks-body-tab)

Of cause removing assembly.info removes the built error.